# The const conundrum in OpenSSL

Tags: c, gcc, openssl, constants

In OpenSSL, some functions require the use of const but then down the road others require me to not use const for the same variable. An example is when I create a new `BIGNUM` I need to use const but then to free it I cannot have const.

Is there a trick to solve this? What would be the proper why to get rid of the compiler warnings?

---

Function signatures:

```
const BIGNUM *EC_KEY_get0_private_key(const EC_KEY *key);
void BN_free(BIGNUM *a);
```

Offending code:

```
EC_KEY *ec_key = ...;
/*const*/ BIGNUM *bignum = NULL;
bignum = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(ec_key);
BN_free(bignum);
```

Compiler warnings:

```
------------Without const in bignum------------:
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  bignum = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(ec_key);
     ^

------------With const in bignum------------:
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘BN_free’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  BN_free(bignum);
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/objects.h:965,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:94,
                 from ecdh.c:5:
/usr/include/openssl/bn.h:493:6: note: expected ‘BIGNUM * {aka struct bignum_st *}’ but argument is of type ‘const BIGNUM * {aka const struct bignum_st *}’
 void BN_free(BIGNUM *a);
```

---

**Edit** to add working example:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
{
    EC_KEY *ec_key = NULL;
    const BIGNUM *bignum = NULL;

    ec_key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    bignum = EC_KEY_get0_private_key(ec_key);

    //BN_free(bignum);    // unnecessary
    EC_KEY_free(ec_key);
    return 0;
}
//$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o leak_ecdh leak_ecdh.c -lcrypto && valgrind --leak-check=yes ./leak_ecdh
//==26202== HEAP SUMMARY:
//==26202==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
//==26202==   total heap usage: 104 allocs, 104 frees, 4,220 bytes allocated
//==26202== 
//==26202== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. Just write const-correct code and check the declarations of the functions. If you don't know what the `const` qualifier is about, a good C book will help.

Comment: @Olaf: What do you mean by "write const-correct code and check the declarations of the functions"? I currently can cast it to make the warning go away but I'm not sure this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Asking what this means clearly indicates you should follow my advice. And no, casts are **never** the correct way if you don't understand **why** an error or warning pops up!

Comment: You deactivated by comment the `/* const */`. What happens if you keep it active?

Comment: If the function returns a pointer to const, then you probably aren't supposed to free the returned value.

Comment: @Yunnosch depending on activating or deactivating the `const` he gets one of the 2 shown warning messages.

Comment: Ah, of course. Sorry.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: "If the function returns a pointer to const, then you probably aren't supposed to free it." --- The function `EC_KEY_get0_private_key` returns a `const BIGNUM *` but then I have to free this using `BN_free` which receives a `BIGNUM *`. So if I use const in the variable I get warning in one function call, if I don't use const I get a warning on the other function call. (I call free because of memory leaks.)

Comment: As mentioned by Daniel, you MUST NOT free the pointer returned by `EC_KEY_get0_private_key`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Actually it seems you're right. I checked with valgrind and I get `in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks` even when I do **not** call `BN_free`.

Comment: @Daniel No new memory is allocated when you call `EC_KEY_get0_private_key`. See the answer of Kevin Boone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me as if the EC_KEY object holds its own copy of the BIGNUM that models the private key:

```
int EC_KEY_set_private_key(EC_KEY *key, const BIGNUM *prv);
```

So when you get a `BIGNUM*` by calling `EC_KEY_get0_private_key()`, I think you're getting a reference to an internal object in the EC_KEY structure. If so, freeing it would be a mistake.

If you had to call a function to allocate a BIGNUM before calling `EC_KEY_set_private_key()`, you could probably free it afterwards, if you didn't need it again, because a copy would be stored in EC_KEY.

This doesn't seem to be well-documented -- I'm guessing based on the C programming conventions rather than actual knowledge.

Using valgrind or similar might help to track down where the memory leak is really coming from.

Comment: OpenSSL's documentation is indeed horrific - too many things are badly documented or not documented at all. I can't blame them - few people can understand it well enough to the point of documenting it properly.

Comment: I confirmed with valgrind that there are no leaks, thank you. I read the man pages of these functions (and I've been looking into the OpenSSL wiki) but this behavior wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto what Kevin Boone said in his answer, it might be useful to remember the difference between getter functions containing **get0** and **get1**.

- **get0** - A reference to the internal object/structure is returned and your application doesn't need to free the memory, OpenSSL takes care of it.
- **get1** - The memory needs to be freed by you by calling the appropriate **free** function.